# Conditionally insert into another table if id exists in another table else insert into both both tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

If customer id exists in table **A**, insert order in table **B**.
if customer id does not exist in table **A**, insert customer id in table **A** and then order in table **B**.
I have been trying to achieve this with **if/else and merge** but keep running into
**invalid sql statement**.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT CustomerID FROM Customer_T WHERE CustomerID = 18)
    Insert into Order_T
    values(79,18,to_date('09/28/2021','mm/dd/yyyy'),to_date('10/01/2021','mm/dd/yyyy'),1,3)
ELSE
  insert INTO Customer_T VALUES (18,'Capitol Industries Ltd', '999 Fifth Avenue', 'New York', 'NY','10015')
  insert into Order_T values (79,18,to_date('09/28/2021','mm/dd/yyyy'),to_date('10/01/2021','mm/dd/yyyy'),1,3)
END IF;
```

Comment: I think that you need a semicolon after each statement. The inserts are statements and the if-else-end if; is one statement. So, just put ; after each insert.

Comment: That didn't work either. Same error

Comment: The requirement looks strange because if you already have some id, then it should come from something. But how can it be absent in the `customer` table?

Comment: So basically a customer must exist before an order can be created. Therefore, it checks if a customer exists, do nothing to customer table but create a new order using that customer id. But if customer does not exist, first create a new customer, and then a new order using that customer id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IF THEN ELSE` logic is not needed for this case. Instead make use of the database built-in functionality. customerid should be your primary key, so if you try to insert and it already exists that will raise the `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` exception.

Check the following example:

```
-- create tables
create table customers (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint customers_id_pk primary key,
    name                           varchar2(255 char)
)
;

create table orders (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint orders_id_pk primary key,
    customer_id                    number
                                   constraint orders_customer_id_fk
                                   references customers on delete cascade,
    product                        varchar2(100 char)
)
;

BEGIN
  BEGIN
    insert INTO customers VALUES (2,'Capitol Industries Ltd');
  EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    NULL; 
  END;
  insert into orders (customer_id,product) values (2,'a book');
END;  
/
```

run the above block a couple of times. Only the first time it will insert a customer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 2 very simple tables.

Tables

```
create table T1( num_ )
as
select 1 from dual ;

create table T2( num_ )
as
select 200 from dual ;
```

An anonymous block, containing IF .. ELSE .. END IF and EXISTS() similar to the code in your question, causes an error:

> function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement
> only

```
    begin
      if exists( select num_ from T1 where num_  = 2 ) then
        insert into T2( num_ ) values( 2 ) ;
        dbms_output.put_line( 'if' ) ;
      else
        insert into T1( num_ ) values( 2 ) ;
        insert into T2( num_ ) values( 2 ) ;
        dbms_output.put_line( 'else' ) ;
      end if ;
    end ;
    /
-- error:
... function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only
```

One solution may be to do the following (see asktom.oracle.com - [Equivalent for EXISTS() in an IF statement](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3069487275935))

```
begin
  for x in ( select count(*) cnt
             from dual
             where exists ( select num_ from T1 where num_  = 2  ) 
  ) loop
    if ( x.cnt = 1 ) then                  -- found
      insert into T2( num_ ) values( 2 ) ;
      dbms_output.put_line( 'if' ) ;
    else                                   -- not found
      insert into T1( num_ ) values( 2 ) ;
      insert into T2( num_ ) values( 2 ) ;
      dbms_output.put_line( 'else' ) ; 
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/

-- output:
1 rows affected

dbms_output:
else
```

After the first execution of the anonymous block, the tables contain the following rows:

```
select num_, '<- T1' as table_ from T1
union all
select num_, '<- T2' from T2 ;

-- result
NUM_    TABLE_
1       <- T1
2       <- T1
200     <- T2
2       <- T2
```

Execute the anonymous block again, and you get ...

```
1 rows affected

dbms_output:
if

-- tables
NUM_    TABLE_
1       <- T1
2       <- T1
200     <- T2
2       <- T2
2       <- T2
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a0bbf904ef425845155fbbfd4135983).

Answer (score 0):

You may use [multitable insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) and use the fact that aggregate function without `group by` always returns a row with `null` in case of absent (= not satisfying `where` condition) row.

The code is below:

> ```
> insert into customers(id, name, company, state)
> values (1, 'Some name', 'Some company', 'NY')
> ```
>
> 1 rows affected

> ```
> insert all
>   when cust_exists = 0
>   then
>     into customers (id, name, company, state)
>     values (cust_id, cust_name, company, state)
>
>   when 1 = 1
>   then
>     into orders (id, customer_id, order_date, due_date, some_id)
>     values(order_id, cust_id, order_date, due_date, some_id)
> select
>   1 as order_id,
>   1 as cust_id,
>   'Some other name' as cust_name,
>   'Company' as company,
>   'NY' as state,
>   date '2021-09-28' as order_date,
>   date '2021-10-03' as due_date,
>   100 as some_id,
>   nvl(max(1), 0) as cust_exists
> from customers
> where id = 1
> ```
>
> 1 rows affected

> ```
> insert all
>   when cust_exists = 0
>   then
>     into customers (id, name, company, state)
>     values (cust_id, cust_name, company, state)
>
>   when 1 = 1
>   then
>     into orders (id, customer_id, order_date, due_date, some_id)
>     values(order_id, cust_id, order_date, due_date, some_id)
> select
>   2 as order_id,
>   2 as cust_id,
>   'Some other name' as cust_name,
>   'Company' as company,
>   'NY' as state,
>   date '2021-09-28' as order_date,
>   date '2021-10-03' as due_date,
>   100 as some_id,
>   nvl(max(1), 0) as cust_exists
> from customers
> where id = 2
> ```
>
> 2 rows affected

You may also use two inserts with [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-20390275-91A7-49DC-AAD1-A1FE943A4F75) `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` hint, which does what its name implies.

> ```
> insert /*+
>   ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(customers(id))
> */
> into customers (id, name, company, state)
> values (2, 'Name', 'Comp', 'NY')
> ```
>
> ✓

> ```
> insert into orders (id, customer_id, order_date, due_date, some_id)
> values (3, 2, date '2021-09-30', date '2021-10-07', 5)
> ```
>
> 1 rows affected

> ```
> select *
> from customers
> ```
>
> | ID | NAME | COMPANY | STATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Some name | Some company | NY |
> | 2 | Some other name | Company | NY |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7131f628b38d8b0ebd51a30c9ca097d5)*